# sort table with multiple related rows per entity

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

How should I solve the following problem> I have data about each entity **in multiple, related rows** in a table (I know using table is obsolate, I should use divs, but I am fine with tables. If div is necessary, I will change.)
I put fresh data into the cells every x seconds based on their ids using jQuery. **I need a javascript function** or something that will allow me to reorder the table **respecting the multiple cohorent rows**. I am open to any other approach.

(PHP part added just for understanding.)

```
<table>
    <?php
    foreach($members as $member)
       {
          //data for this member starts here

         echo"<tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>score:1000</td>
                <td>MAX score:2000</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>somevalue:3000</td>
                <td>another value:4000</td>
                <td>another value:4000</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                  <td collspan=‘3'>This is a row for separate the members</td>
             </tr>
             ";
       //data for this member ends here
       }
?>
</table>
```

For example I would like to sort based on the score. The sorting should carry the row containing the “somevalue” and the separator row as well to the new “position”.

Comment: Hint: A table can have one or more `tbody` elements

Comment: Why minus?  It is a problem for me, with proper format. I asked for a solution not for just throwing a minus.

Comment: Did you at least try something ?

Comment: Users are allowed to upvote and downvote questions, that's one of the main feature of SE sites. Regarding the downvote, maybe *"I need a javascript function"* in a bold type has something to do with it.

Comment: sure. but none of them worth to litter

Comment: @ Andreas. Thanks for pointing me to the “tbody". That is the solution

Comment: "I put fresh data into the cells every x seconds based on their ids" - Do you refresh all or just add new ones?  If added, do you want to resort after adding?  If just refresh, that would seem to be fairly simple, just sort before placing onto the table.

Comment: Remember to add your final solution as an answer to "mark" this question as solved.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss I add new content with ajax call. After that I Would like to call the requested function that will sort the table.

Comment: @ Andreas. I will. But need time to work it out.

Comment: If you're changing the markup I would suggest to either add a class on the cell of the score, which makes it a little easier to extract the value for the comparison in the sort function. Or, if possible, at the sort criteria with a `data-*` attribute to the enclosing `tbody` element (`<tbody data-score="<score>">...</tbody>`) which makes it even easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to go out on a limb here and give you one option.  Put the data into single rows in a set of `div` and `span` to simulate the markup of table rows and cells.  Note you will have to style these to better emulate that.  (perhaps bootstrap `row` etc. but I will leave that to  you), key here is the sort.

Here to simplify the logic I put a numeric value in a data attribute on each row, then sort rows by that.

Note: assumptions made of single `tbody`, has that, single sort value, numeric data value etc.

IF you wanted you could put multiple 'tbody' with data attributes and sort those - I will leave that exercise to you but the `flow` my get slow on large sets of data.

NOTE: call the sort whenever you render or add.  You could also avoid the subsequent sorts, simply inserting rows after the one before.

Example to insert (might be better but enough to start with)

```
  var $newRow = $('<tr data-sortdata="5"><td>putalldivs in here<td></tr>');
  var rowToInsertBefore = $('#mytable').find('tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('sortdata') >= $newRow.data('sortdata');
  }).get(0);

  if (typeof rowToInsertBefore === 'undefined') {
    $('#mytable').find('tbody').append($newRow);
  } else {
    $newRow.insertBefore(rowToInsertBefore);
  }
```

The bulk of the code to sort:

```js
function sortTable(table, order, item) {
  var asc = order === 'asc',
    tbody = table.find('tbody'),
    sd = item ? item : "sortdata";
  tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    var sA = 1 * $(a).data(sd);
    var sB = 1 * $(b).data(sd);
    if (asc) {
      return (sA < sB) ? -1 : (1 * sA > sB) ? 1 : 0;
    } else {
      return (sB < sA) ? -1 : (sB > sA) ? 1 : 0;
    }
  }).appendTo(tbody);
}
sortTable($('#mytable'), 'asc', 'sortdata');
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  border: solid 1px lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-sortdata="3000">
      <td>
        <div>
          <span>John</span>
          <span>score:1000</span>
          <span>MAX score:2000</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>somevalue:3000</span>
          <span>another value:4000</span>
          <span>another value:4000</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>This is a row for separate the members</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-sortdata="5000">
      <td>
        <div>
          <span>Brenda</span>
          <span>score:3000</span>
          <span>MAX score:2000</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>somevalue:5000</span>
          <span>another value:4000</span>
          <span>another value:4000</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>This is a row for separate the members</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-sortdata="1000">
      <td>
        <div>
          <span>Harry</span>
          <span>score:1000</span>
          <span>MAX score:500</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>somevalue:1000</span>
          <span>another value:4000</span>
          <span>another value:4000</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>This is a row for separate the members</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-sortdata="1000">
      <td>
        <div>
          <span>Brenda1</span>
          <span>score:3000</span>
          <span>MAX score:2000</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>somevalue:1000</span>
          <span>another value:4000</span>
          <span>another value:4000</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>This is a row for separate the members</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will go on with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out, but I think I will rework Mark Schultheiss’s solution and use that one. More elegant..

EDITED: added some tweeks:

1, if you have more tables in webpage, you have to add class identifier..

2, If you have also non numeric stuff in the cell, like text, etc but you want to sort based on the numeric value part=> put a div class in cell surrounding the number..

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sort").click(function () {
var $tBodies = $('.klantabla tbody').sort(function(b, a){
         var aVal = +($(a).find('tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) div.num').text().trim() || 0);
         var bVal = +($(b).find('tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) div.num').text().trim() || 0);
         return aVal - bVal;
    });
    $(‘.klantabla').append($tBodies);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="sort by 3rd row, 3rd column " id="sort" />
<table border=‘1' class=‘klantabla'>
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="member-1">
        <tr>
            <td>3 member1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><div class=’num’>SOME SCORE 9</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2 member1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1 member1</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">SAPARTOR for member1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="member-3">
        <tr>
            <td>3 member3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>11111111115</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2 member3</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1 member3</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">SEPARATOR for member3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="member-2">
        <tr>
            <td>3 member2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2 member2</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1 member2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>999</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">SEPARATOR for member2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```